# USB hubs that actually implements Hub Port Power Control?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, lsusb

No USB hub I have tried actually seems to support "Hub Port Power Control" properly that is required for USB 2.0 compliance.

The USB 2.0 standard states that :

> Self-powered hubs may have power switches that control delivery of
>   power downstream facing ports but it is not required.  Bus-powered
>   hubs are required to have power switches.  A hub with power switches
>   can switch power to all ports as a group/gang, to each port
>   individually, or have an arbitrary number of gangs of one or more
>   ports. A hub indicates whether or not it supports power switching by
>   the setting of the Logical Power Switching Mode field in
>   wHubCharacteristics.  If a hub supports per-port power switching, then
>   the power to a port is turned on when a SetPortFeature(PORT_POWER)
>   request is received for the port.  Port power is turned off when the
>   port is in the Powered-off or Not Configured states.  If a hub
>   supports ganged power switching, then the power to all ports in a gang
>   is turned on when any port in a gang receives a
>   SetPortFeature(PORT_POWER) request.  The power to a gang is not turned
>   off unless all ports in a gang are in the Powered-off or Not
>   Configured states.

And

> Although a self-powered hub is not required to implement power
>   switching, the hub must support the Powered-off state for all ports. 
>   Additionally, the hub must implement the PortPwrCtrlMask  (all bits
>   set to 1B) even though the hub has no power switches that can be
>   controlled by the USB System Software.

http://www.makelinux.net/lib/usb/2/USB_2.0_Specification/doc-363

In Linux most chipsets seems to support this feature when doing `lusb -v` as specified under the `wHubCharacteristics` field. But when actually trying to use it nothing happens, it is not possible to turn off the power for any port (or even all of them).

I guess this is because the hardware manufacturers never bothered to actually wire up this support, even though the chipset support it, leading people to do hacks like [this](http://hackaday.com/2014/02/05/software-controlled-per-port-power-switching-for-usb-hubs/)

So my question is:

**Does anyone have a list with hardware the properly support USB Port Power control?**

Specifically it would be nice with both model and batch numbers, since support may differ between different revisions.

Related links:

[Disable USB powered light from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/314402/disable-usb-powered-light-from-command-line)

http://www.gniibe.org/development/ac-power-control-by-USB-hub/index.html

Comment: This is not a hardware shopping topic. It is a general compatability question regarding a widely used technology. USB.

Comment: Asking if *anything exists* that does a certain thing is not a prohibited shopping question.

Comment: Thank you @endolith, I agree of course :) Especially since this is kind of weird that almost no manufacturer seem to follow the specs

Comment: I would add this as answer if I could. I am maintaining​ list of USB hubs that support per port power switching at https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl